# What is the reason behind me getting such and error in java?

Tags: java

```java
package Akash;
public class hell
{
    public static long toMilesPerHour (double kilometersPerHour) {

        if (kilometersPerHour < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            long milesPerHour = Math.round(kilometersPerHour / 1.609);
            return milesPerHour;
        }
    }

    public static void printConversion (double kilometersPerHour) {

        if (kilometersPerHour < 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Value");
        }
        else {
            long miles = toMilesPerHour(kilometersPerHour);
            System.out.println(kilometersPerHour + " km/h = " + miles + " mi/h");
        }
    }
}
```

Error: Main method not found in class Akash.hell, please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: Lol this happens when you don’t have a public static void main(String [] args) { ... method

Comment: you dont have any main method in your program

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The answer on your question is in error message. You have to define `main` method, which is entry point of your application:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // invoke your static methods from here or create some new object and invoke its method
}
```

Are you familiar with java basics? You can learn more about `main` method here: [Java main method](https://www.journaldev.com/12552/public-static-void-main-string-args-java-main-method).

Answer (score 1):

Main method is missing in your program, it should look like this

```
public class Cash{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hell.printConversion(10);
    }
}
```